# How to export multiple files from one select in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I m beginner with HIVE and Hadoop.I have a file loaded in a hive table like this :

```
 YEAR;DEP;CAP

 2012;1;6774

 2013;1;7082

 2014;1;6377

 2015;1;7319

 2005;94;7893

 2006;94;8620

 2007;94;8144
```

I would like to have n flat files in output, grouped by DEP, and 
named datafile_DEP :

> **first file**

```
 2012;1;6774

 2013;1;7082

 2014;1;6377

 2015;1;7319
```

> **second file**

```
 2005;94;7893

 2006;94;8620

 2007;94;8144
```

and so on. Each time I have a new DEP create new file for it.

How can i do that ? many thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't provide any utility out of the box to create file with defined file name.

You can solve half of the problem using hive dynamic partition, read [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions). Create another table partitioned on `DEP` column then load data.

```
--Actual table
create table source (year int, cap int, dep int) ...

--Partitioned table
create table dep_partitioned (year int, cap int) PARTITIONED BY ( dep int) ....
--Enable dynamic partition 

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=non-strict

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dep_partitioned PARTITION (dep)
SELECT year, cap, dep FROM source;
```

As Hive partitions data stored on HDFS directories and each partition column value conform to separate HDFS path. Each DEP value will have separate directory on dep_partitioned table location, next for each DEP directory create separate file using bash script.

I hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks to have taken the time to analyse my problem...yes , i thougth also to the partitionning (as seen on over topic) ...it could be relevant !